# Customizing metaMDS() plot

Tags: r, vegan

I have created a NMDS plot using the 'vegan' package, like this:

```
y=metaMDS(data,type="p").
plot(y)
```

Now I have this NMDS with a good spread of my points. However, I would like to add the graphics of the plot. I would like to give the points in the plot a different colour, depending on a categorical variable (the variable is called 'regio') in my dataset, which has two values (1 or 2).

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Best,
Koen

Comment: [This answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Vegan-plotting-color-help-td846548.html) on R-help list will guide you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the grouping variable `regio` to index into a vector of colours you want to plot with. E.g., (untested as I don't have your `data`...)

```
colvec <- c("red","blue")
plot(y, type = "n")
points(y, display = "sites", col = colvec[data$regio])
## or
text(y, display = "sites", col = colvec[data$regio])
## depending on how you want to represent the sample scores
```